# How to use a formatted string to access SUB properties in a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript

For the sake of reusable code, I am trying to avoid having to hardcode literally thousands of complex objects by instead using strings like "foo.bar.sub" to access properties.

Now I have quickly worked out a naive algorithm for **getting** the value of a property, like so:

```
getValueForPath : function(path) {
    var pathArray = path.split('.'),
        modelCopy = this;
    while (pathArray.length > 0) {
        modelCopy = modelCopy[pathArray.shift()];
    }
    return modelCopy;
},
```

However this will only return the value of a property, not let me **set** the value of a property.  So it is only one half of the problem.  Ideally I need a way to, for a given path, return the property *itself*, which i'm not sure is possible in JavaScript(But i'm not a JavaScript expert), or I need a second function to set the property for a given path, and I have so far been unable to work this out.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use another function, you can use

```
getValueForPath("foo.bar").sub = something;
```

Alternatively,

```
setValueForPath: function(path, val) {
    var pathArray = path.split('.'),
        modelCopy = this;
    while (pathArray.length > 1) {
        modelCopy = modelCopy[pathArray.shift()];
    }
    return modelCopy[pathArray[0]] = val;
}
getValueForPath("foo.bar.sub", something);
```

Also consider unifying both functions:

```
accessValueForPath: function(path, val) {
    var pathArray = path.split('.'),
        modelCopy = this,
        b = val!==void 0;
    while (pathArray.length > b) {
        modelCopy = modelCopy[pathArray.shift()];
    }
    return b ? modelCopy[pathArray[0]] = val : modelCopy;
}
accessValueForPath("foo.bar.sub"); // read
accessValueForPath("foo.bar.sub", something); // write
```

Comment: I already thought of that but unless i'm being stupid, that won't work because this naive function works on a COPY of the object, since it pseudo-recursively chops its way down.

Comment: @jwvanderbeck In javascript, variables are assigned by value which, in case of objects, is a reference. Therefore, if you modify a property, you will affect all variables that reference the same object. However, note that setting `modelCopy` to something at the end of your code wouldn't work, you must stop at the previous step and then modify a property.

Comment: "However, note that setting modelCopy to something at the end of your code wouldn't work, you must stop at the previous step and then modify a property."   That was the key I was missing, which is why I thought it was working as a true copy.  Thanks!