# Drill down into Javascript object using array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of strings which work as a 'path' to a certain property of a JavaScript object:

```
var car = {
 "owner": "Joe",
 "model": {
   name: "Ford",
   "manufacturer": {
      "founder": "Henry Ford"
   }
 }
};

var address = ["model", "manufacturer", "founder"];
```

I want to write a function which will use that address to find the property of the object which lies at the end of the path, in the example, return "Henry Ford". I want the function to be able to handle addresses of arbitrary length. What would this function look like?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use a formatted string to access SUB properties in a JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26513905/how-to-use-a-formatted-string-to-access-sub-properties-in-a-javascript-object), but I know I've seen others as well.

Comment: Though it's not advisable, you can do `eval('car.' + address.join('.'))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with `.reduce()`

```
var value = address.reduce(function(o, name) { return o && o[name]; }, car);
```

The `.reduce()` function starts off with an initial "accumulator" value, which will be the `car` object here. It iterates through the array, passing in each value and expecting the next accumulator value to be returned. Each step just looks up the property value and returns it, or the accumulator itself it it's falsey.

Answer (score 1):

This will handle the case the search fails too. Plus, it's easy to understand from just looking at the code.

**Input**: Object, Array

**Output**: found key, or null otherwise

```
function searchObject(root, pathArray) {
    var node = root;
    for(var index in pathArray) {
        key = pathArray[index];
        if(key in node) {
            node = node[key];
        } else {
            node = null;
            break;
        }
    }
    return node;
}
```

Example:

```
var car = {
 "owner": "Joe",
 "model": {
   name: "Ford",
   "manufacturer": {
      "founder": "Henry Ford"
   }
 }
};
```

and

```
var address = ["model", "manufacturer", "founder"];
```

then `searchObject(car, address)` returns "Henry Ford".

Answer (score 0):

Try ...

```
function getValue(ob, address) {
  result = ob;
  for (var i=0,len=address.length; i<len; i++) {
    result = result[address[i]];
  }
  return result;
}
```

This should return the object or value at the end of the address list.